# How will the blog be accessed when it is launched?

Tags: support, blog

Given that the blog is finally getting underway. I was wondering; how will we access it when it launches? Will it be up with the chat/faq bar or will it be somewhere else? How will people know that we have one? Side link? Banner ad?

Answer (score 2):

The `blog` link in the footer will change from:

http://blog.stackexchange.com/?blb=1

to:

http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/?blb=1

Then when there's a new post the `chat` link in the header will be replaced by the `blog` link for 24 hours.

Contributors will have to bookmark the link for accessing the blog dashboard themselves.

Comment: Good to know. Much obliged.